# MsXML calls IIS published .net but it wouldn't pass the parameters to web method

Tags: web-services, iis-7.5, magik

We have a web service scenario in which the caller(wrote in Magik(r) programming language ) uses MSXML 6.0 to send a prepared SOAP xml to a webservice. the web method is written in C# using Visual studio 2012 and is published on IIS 7.5 (windows server 2012)

**Problem is** : the web method does not recieve the parameters, it is called with null arguments to be exact.

It also raises an exception "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" which shows the above situation.

Could this be a compatibility issue? Since all parts are Microsoft technologies it seems a little bit odd but here is some results that may help finding out the calprit.

1. The caller program works perfect with other .net webservices and sends parameters flawlessly
2. The caller also works fine with our webservice (in scenario) if the webservice has no parameters.
3. The webservice works fine with callers application if they are written in .net

Comment: Hi any Idea where to find other Magik developers? this is the only question regarding magik in SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in defining tempuri address. Which should be similar to wsdl but since I was creating the xml myself and sending it through msxml I set the tempuri address wrong which leaded to the problem.

Strange that Microsoft is that sensetive on tempuri, axis webservice don't!